# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "dar la lata"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

En España se utiliza con frecuencia la expresión "dar la lata" (o "dar el coñazo", algo más burda) cuando alguien es muy reiterativo:

> - Mamá ¿puedo ir a jugar con mis amigos?
> - No.
> - Pero mamá...
> - ¡No y no des más la lata! Estás castigado hasta que no hagas los deberes, así que no insistas.

Leo en [¿Sabías el origen de la expresión "dar la lata"?](http://www.aulafacil.com/articulos/sabias/t1329/el-origen-de-la-expresion-dar-la-lata) diferentes posibles orígenes de la expresión:

> La primera de ellas hace referencia al tubo de lata en el que llevaban
>   los soldados viejos unos papeles que demostraban sus hazañas bélicas o
>   que acreditaban el buen servicio prestado a la patria (allá por el
>   siglo XVII), y que solían acompañarles cuando visitaban los despachos
>   de sus superiores en busca de alguna pensión o compensación económica
>   por los servicios prestados y las secuelas que estos les habían dejado
>   en sus cuerpos.
>
> Otra versión nos lleva hasta Málaga (España), donde al parecer en la
>   cárcel se solía vender a los presidiarios un licor hecho a base de
>   sobras de varios vinos y que éstos compraban por latas, lo que les
>   proporcionaba una incontestable borrachera que se traducía en alboroto
>   y jaleo; resultando tremendamente molesto para el resto de
>   presidiarios y personal de vigilancia.
>
> Finalmente también se cita el uso de latas en las cencerradas que se
>   celebraban en distintas localidades como celebración por los segundos
>   casamientos de alguien que había quedado viudo/a.

Así que me pregunto: ¿alguien sabe cuál es la más verosímil? Además, ¿se usa en otros países? Por la primera explicación parecería que no y que es típica de España solamente.

Comment: En Chile se usa también, e incluso usamos el adjetivo `latero` (y en muy menor medida `latoso`), y que según la RAE se usa en algunos países de América (Arg., Bol., Chile, Hond., Nic., R. Dom. y Ur.). Y también tenemos el verbo `latear`, que es sinónimo directo de `dar la lata`.

Comment: @Nicolás caramba, es curioso porque `latero` ahora en España solamente se utiliza para aquellas personas que venden latas (de cerveza normalmente) en las calles. `latoso` sí lo he oído alguna vez en España. ¿Será que, si el origen válido es el primero, saltó a América del Sur con tanta ida y vuelta de gente? : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi granito de arena con otras referencias

> En la columna de opinión titulada *El rollo*, que apareció publicada en el diario El País el 6 de junio de 1999, Carreter explica así el **posible origen** de la expresión: "daban la lata los soldados viejos que, en el siglo XVII, andaban de despacho en despacho mendigando compensaciones a sus cicatrices y a las proezas que adveraba aquel rollo de **documentos metidos en un tubo de lata**". El académico también señala que de esta costumbre militar pudo surgir "la **equivalencia hoy perfecta de latazo y rollo**".
>
> Fuente [Muy interesante](http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/icual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-dar-la-lata)

Esta me gusta porque el tal Carreter era el que escribía mis libros de Lengua Castellana del EGB (y quizá los del BUP también).

La web, [*Etimologías de Chile*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?lata) apunta a otro origen, basado en el molesto ruido al golpear una lámina de latón. Latón, viene del latín *latta*.

Esta otra web, Yorokobu, tiene un [artículo](http://www.yorokobu.es/dar-la-lata/) basado en el libro *El porqué de los dichos* de José María Iribarren, según el cual el origen estaría otra vez en un ruido molesto: en el de latas vacías que se arrastraban o pegaban con un palo.

[Esta otra web](http://www.centrohermes.com.ar/lecturaamena/Interesante/origen_de_frases.htm) comparte también opinión sobre el significado

> Parece provenir de los segundos festejos nupciales de una viuda o viudo, en los que solía usarse instrumentos de percusión.

Dado que no se citan referencias es imposible saber si los dos beben de la misma fuente, se copia una a la otra o si "validan" el origen de la expresión.

El artículo de Yokorobu cita otras referencias para el origen de la expresión (añadiendo entonces confusión sobre cuál es realmente el posible origen) entre ellas una de Dámaso Alonso para decir que

> lata en español puede tener el mismo significado que latte en francés: o sea, palo. Al igual que sus derivados ‘lato’, ‘late’o ‘latta’ en provenzal, italiano o portugués. Y que latazo tiene el sentido de ‘golpe con la lata, con un palo’.

Aunque *latte* en francés significa `regla` o `listón`, la web indica que

> Según don Dámaso, este uso de ‘latazo’ como ‘dar palos, golpes’ [... unido al uso ...] de la lata (hojalata) cambió las cosas y en algún momento la palabrita dejó de identificar al palo o la maza. Sin embargo, su sentido de “molestia, aburrimiento” sí trascendió.

Hay que indicar que la propia RAE dice que la etimología de ["lata"](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Mxzdak6) es discutida. Para ["latón"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=lat%C3%B3n) en cambio la tiene clara.

Así que no he podido encontrar una referencia que sea completamente creíble. Yo en cualquier caso me inclino por pensar que viene por el ruido de las latas o láminas de latón (como en la referencia atribuida a Dámaso Alonso o a la de los festejos municipales de los viudos en segundas nupcias).

Comment: Muchas gracias por el análisis comparado y la conclusión final. A mí me gusta más la hipótesis de Lázaro Carreter (el de "El dardo en la palabra", ¿verdad?) pero como en muchos de estos casos es prácticamente imposible determinar. Miré en Google Ngram Viewer y parece que [comienza a aparecer alrededor de 1900](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dar+la+lata&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdar%20la%20lata%3B%2Cc0). No sé cómo interpretar este hecho más allá de que la historia del siglo XVII pillaría algo lejos.

Comment: Sí, a mi la de Carreter me gustaba más, pero tampoco conseguí encontrar una fuente fiable, y las otras acerca del ruido me parecían más razonables. Por eso, aparte de enumerar todo lo que había podido encontrar, decidí ofrecer una opinión personal. Aun así, **no creo que esta deba ser la respuesta aceptada**. He aportado _otras_ referencias, pero no he aclarado más de lo que tú ya tenías en la pregunta. Quizá deberíamos dejar pasar más tiempo, a ver si alguien descubre alguna otra cosa, y aporta fuentes más fiables (cosa que también es más probable si no hay ya una respuesta aceptada).